# How to map many columns into one column

Tags: python, pandas

First data frame:

```
name        age   sex
smith row   26    male
sam smith   30    male
susan storm   25  female
```

Second data frame:

```
name        age   sex    nick_name
smith row   26    male   smity
sam smith   30    male   sammy
susan storm   25  female suanny
```

Output expected:

```
name         age   sex
smith row   26    male
sam smith   30    male
susan storm   25  female
smity             m
sammy             m
suanny            f
```

How can I dynamically map from other df to other df column?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do here.  Can you explain in detail how you go from two dataframes of three to one dataframe of six with nick_name and name in the same column.

Comment: @ScottBoston its my requirement i just want to map other column from other df to other column in df

Comment: Map which column to which column?   Where do the m, m, f come from?

Comment: You're not mapping anything. Also the logic is unclear, what should happen if the order of the names is different? Finally, what is the point of this final format? It uses more space and doesn't efficiently/unambiguously allow to read the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to modify df2 to get the result you want.

```
df2['name'] = df2['nick_name']
df2['sex'] = df2['sex'].str[0]
df2 = df2.drop(columns=['age', 'nick_name'])

df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

this is the end result

```
name         age    sex
smith row    26     male
sam smith    30     male
susan storm  25     female
smity        NaN    m
sammy        NaN    m
suanny       NaN    f
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `concat` function in python. This should work.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'name': ['smith row', 'sam smith', 'susan storm'],
         'age': [26, 30, 25],
         'sex': ['male', 'male', 'female']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'name': ['smith row', 'sam smith', 'susan storm'],
         'age': [26, 30, 25],
         'sex': ['male', 'male', 'female'],
         'nick_name': ['smity m', 'sammy m', 'suanny f']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

# Concatenating the columns
result = pd.concat([df1, df2['nick_name']], ignore_index=True)

# result
print(result)
```

Comment: Can u check my post again? I just edit thank you.

Comment: Have a look at `map` function or `merge` function in pandas.